# IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, list

I have a problem, I need the help of everyone.
I read rar file (100mb) and process text file (include in rarfile).

```
import glob
import os
import UnRAR2
from os import path, access, R_OK
os.chdir("E:\\sms")
for file in glob.glob("*.rar"):
# extract test.txt to memory
    entries = UnRAR2.RarFile(file).read_files('*.txt')
    test_content = entries[0][1]
    #print test_content
    for line in test_content.split("\n"):
        A=line.split(' ')
        print A[1]
```

Result:

```
19009057

7030

9119

9119

....

....

bla...bla...

......

9119

9119

9119

7050

9119

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\LAPTRINH\Android\adt-bundle-windows\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "E:\LAPTRINH\Android\adt-bundle-windows\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\The\Documents\workspace\unrar\test_unrar.py", line 13, in <module>
    print A[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please, help me!
Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks like one of your lines doesn't have any spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your lines (probably your last) is not in the format you expect. Do this in your inner for loop:

```
A=line.split(' ')
if len(A) > 1:
    print A[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`A[1]` would be suspect if the last line in your file was `\n`.  You'd want to rethink the way you're pulling info back.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that  the content of `line` split up, `A`, doesn't have a second item, which means that it doesn't have anything left to parse, and you're at the end of the file.